# using cURL: Illegal Characters found in URL

Tags: curl

Trying to use curl to download tiff data with the specified parameters. When I execute the request below I get the error:  curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL. Any idea why this is the case?

```
curl "http://aws.wfas.net/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0
         &request=execute
         &identifier=gs:LandscapeExport
         &DataInputs=Longitude=-114;Latitude=45;
         version=LF140;
         Scale+Factor=1;
         Extent=5
         &RawDataOutput=output" -o landscape.tiff
```

Comment: I'm not sure what platform you are on, and _how_ you execute this reqest, but for me the request works (if I put it all on one line)